# Can I use methods from .java file in Xcode project?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Can I use methods from `.java` file in Xcode project (iPhone/iPad)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [J2ObjC](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/) that translates Java to ObjC!

> J2ObjC is an open-source command-line tool from Google that translates Java code to Objective-C for the iOS (iPhone/iPad) platform. This tool enables Java code to be part of an iOS application's build, as no editing of the generated files is necessary. The goal is to write an app's non-UI code (such as data access, or application logic) in Java, which is then shared by web apps (using GWT), Android apps, and iOS apps.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to do some porting of your own.

Comment: Can you guide me on this. I never worked on these kind of projects before.

Comment: I got this link when I did some R&D on this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040321163154226 Do I need to follow the same steps?

Comment: Interesting, looks worth the try. Either this or 'recreate the wheel' in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't as is a different language/syntax.